# GTK3 Update Menu bar and menu item

Tags: c, menuitem, updates, menubar, gtk3

I have a question to ask you.
I want to make a menu updatable using a value of a int variable (If the value of the variable changes are also modified the menu items). I know the possibility to update the string of a single menu item when its is clicked (by the creation of a function in signal connect() that update the single string of the menu item), but for the first case i don't have find nothing in internet for now!
Thank you!

Comment: You really should publish the code you wrote so far if you want others to assist you with it.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it.

You don't need to wrap a simple integer in all the GTK+ object and event machinery; if you know when the value changes, you can just compute a new label text for the menu item and set it (using [`gtk_menu_item_set_label()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkMenuItem.html#gtk-menu-item-set-label)).